# How can I pass an input value to a parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-forms

I have a form component where I create the template of fields that can be initiated in another component, then in the parent component's template, I define fields properties. Problem is that my form submit button is in the parent component which means I have no access to input values from here.

This is Parent component:

```
function SignIn() {
   //Here I will be doing API call and will need to use input values 
};

function Login() {
        let template = {
            fields: [
                {
                    title: data.email,
                    type: 'email',
                    name: data.email,
                    placeholder: data.inputPlaceholder,
                    icon: letter,
                },
                {
                    title: data.password,
                    type: 'password',
                    name: data.password,
                    placeholder: data.inputPlaceholder,
                    icon: lock,
                }
            ]
        }

        return (
           <Form template={template} />
           <Button btnstyle={'mazhrBtn light-green'} onClick={SignIn}>
              {data.signInButton}
           </Button>
        );
    }
```

This is Form component:

```
function Form({ template, children, onSubmit, errors }) {

    const [ value , setValue ] = useState('');
    let [ formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState(false);

    let { fields } = template;

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        onSubmit({
            text: value
        });

        if(errors) {
            formErrors = true;
            setFormErrors(formErrors);
        } else {
            formErrors = false;
            setFormErrors(formErrors);
            event.target.reset();
            document.querySelector('.editable').innerHTML = "";
        }
    };

    const renderFields = (fields) => {
        return fields.map((field, index) => {
            let { title, type, name, placeholder, icon, textArea, dropdown, dropdownTemplate } = field;

            const onChange = (event) => {

                let eName = event.target.name;
                let eValue = event.target.value;

                setValue({
                    ...value,
                    [eName]: eValue
                });

                console.log(eName + ':' + eValue);

                if(icon) {
                    if (event.target.value !== '') {
                        document.getElementById('icon' + index).classList.add('active');
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('icon' + index).classList.remove('active');
                    }
                }
            };

            return (
                <div key={index} className="form-field">
                    <label htmlFor={name}>{title}</label>
                    <div className="input-wrapper">
                        {dropdown ? 
                        
                        <DropdownButton dropdownTemplate={dropdownTemplate} placeholder={placeholder} customClass='input'/>
                        :
                        
                        textArea ?
                        <p  className="m-0 editable"
                            contentEditable
                            type={type}
                            name = {name}
                            id={name}
                            placeholder={placeholder}
                            value={index.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
                            onInput={ 
                                e => setValue(
                                    {
                                        ...value,
                                        [e.target.getAttribute("name")]: e.currentTarget.textContent
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        ></p>
                        :
                        <input
                            type={type}
                            name={name}
                            id={name}
                            placeholder={placeholder}
                            value={index.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                        />
                        }
                        {icon ? <img id={'icon' + index} className="icon" src={icon} alt="icon"/> : ''}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                { renderFields(fields) }
                {children}
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Sorry in advance for a messy code, I'm learning React

Comment: You can pass the `onClick` handler as a prop to the form component too. Then the form component can call `onClick` with all the values of the form as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you need the state in a parent component, the best thing to do is to lift the state up. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

That means moving your state hooks to the parent component and passing them down as props to the child component